# Add weight in nodes and change the line width of node in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following Latex code that draw a weighted graph

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt,
    color = orange,
    labelcolor = gray!30,
    labelstyle = {draw}]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
    \SetGraphUnit{3}
    \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
    \Vertex[x=2,y=1]{S}
    \Vertex[x=5,y=2]{A}
    \Vertex[x=5,y=-1]{B}
    \Vertex[x=7,y=-1]{D}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=2]{C}
    \Vertex[x=7,y=-3]{E}
    \Vertex[x=11,y=1]{G}    
    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
    \Edge[label=$9$](S)(G)
    \Edge[label=$1$](S)(B)
    \Edge[label=$2$](S)(A)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(C)
    \Edge[label=$3$](A)(D)
    \Edge[label=$2$](B)(D)
    \Edge[label=$4$](B)(E)
    \Edge[label=$4$](C)(G)
    \Edge[label=$4$](D)(G)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to add weight in or above nodes and change the line width of node G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a vertex line width, do it right before its definition with:
`\renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{2pt}`.

To add nodes anywhere around vertices, do it naturally:
`\path (A) node[above=10pt] {your weight};`.

There are many examples in the manual that would help you find ways to improve your graphs.

[image: tkz-graph modifications]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetUpEdge[lw = 1.5pt,
    color = orange,
    labelcolor = gray!30,
    labelstyle = {draw}]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
    \SetGraphUnit{3}
    \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
    \Vertex[x=2,y=1]{S}
    \Vertex[x=5,y=2]{A}
    \Vertex[x=4,y=-1]{B}
    \Vertex[x=6,y=-1]{D}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=2]{C}
    \Vertex[x=7,y=-3]{E}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{2pt}
    \Vertex[x=11,y=1]{G}    
    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
    \Edge[label=$9$](S)(G)
    \Edge[label=$1$](S)(B)
    \Edge[label=$2$](S)(A)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(C)
    \Edge[label=$3$](A)(D)
    \Edge[label=$2$](B)(D)
    \Edge[label=$4$](B)(E)
    \Edge[label=$4$](C)(G)
    \Edge[label=$4$](D)(G)
    
    \path (A) node[above=10pt] {your weight};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```